# ActiveRecord#exists? or rescue from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound

Tags: ruby-on-rails, exception, activerecord

What is the recommended way of handling the following type of situations:

Supposing I have a model called `Cart`, that has a 1-1 relationship with the model `Person` and the same PK (the user's id).

In the `index` method of my `cart_controller` I want to check if a `Cart` exists for the current user.
If I do `Cart.find(the_user_id)` and a cart doesn't exists a `RecordNotFound` exception gets raised.

I see two ways of solving this:

#### 1. rescue from the exception

```
 begin
    @cart = Cart.find(the_user_id)
    #more code here
 rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
    #the cart is empty message
 end
```

#### 2. use ActiveRecord#exists? method

```
 if Cart.exists?(the_user_id)
    @cart = Cart.find(the_user_id)
    #more code here
 else
    #the cart is empty message
 end
```

From my (limited) knowledge on exeption handling I know that it's not recommended to use exceptions this way, but is making an extra query every time worth it?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You could try asking the user object for its cart. Let's say you have the user assigned to `@user` then if the user has a cart it would be `@user.cart`. If `@user.cart` is `nil` then they don't have one.

This assumes that you have the relationships between the models set up correctly.

Comment: +1, ok. this sounds like the best way to go in this case. unfortunately my problem with #exists? vs rescue didn't get the argument sustained, good answer I was hoping for

Comment: not sure what you mean by sustained argument. If you use cart = Cart.find(:id) then if its not found you will get an error which you have to trap using rescue. If you use cart = Cart.find_by_id(:id) then  cart will be nil which you can test for.

@user.cart will be nil or the cart which is very easy to test for. You can do something like

if @cart = @user.cart 
 #do cart stuff
else
 # do no cart stuff
end

Comment: Yes, in this case this is definitely the best thing to do. But I was considering a general case, when I have to call a model directly (no associations) (eg find by id). Seems like I got the answer to that too, with find_by_id, which does not raise an execption.

Comment: Actually in your case you would need to use Cart.find_by_user_id(user_id)

Answer (score 34):

Use find_by_id instead of find:

```
@cart = Cart.find_by_id(params[:id])
```

nil's if it does not exist so you can check "if @cart" in your controller/view as needed

Comment: +1 Interesting. Good to know. Thanks. I'm gonna go with @user.cart in this case though.

Comment: John's answer is closer to your problem domain than mine, but think of if as an extra tool if the model does not belongs to another, (i.e is a Singleton or a root model)

Comment: Some nasty hack here. Love it! +1

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you do something like...

```
@cart = @user.cart || @user.cart.new
```

No worrying about exceptions or if/else statements.
Then in your view you could have something like...

```
<% if @cart.empty? # or whatever method you use to determine 
     # if there is nothing in the cart...maybe .blank? is fine? 
%>
    <p>Your cart is empty</p>
<% else %>
    <!-- loop through objects in your cart -->
<% end %>
```

Comment: +1 yeah, @user.cart was the thing to do and not calling the Cart model directly. I accepted Lee Irving's answer though, because he was the first

Comment: This ought to be `@user.build_cart`.

Answer (score 0):

exists? would result in one more SQL statement, unless ActiveRecord guys optimized this out (I wouldn't count on that).

So I'd advise to use an exception, it's much cheaper than a SQL statement.

Comment: ActiveRecord has a pretty good query cache now. You really shouldn't use exceptions for control flow.

Comment: Agreed, no exception necessary as this isn't really an exceptional situation, it most likely is going to happen a lot.

Comment: also, performance-wise, .create + rescue RecordNotUnique will instantiate AR object and make an attempt to create with SQL query while exists? will run very simple, short query before you initialize new object.
On the other hand, if chances of duplicate record are low, method with rescue may be faster in general.